# Reading only letters in C using fscanf

Tags: c

Is it possible to use `fscanf` to read words without symbols from a text file

this function prints one word on a single line but if the word had comma or brackets it will print those too is there anyway to only print letters?

```c
void load(const char *file)
{
    FILE *inFile = fopen(file , "r");
    if (inFile == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    char word[LENGTH];
    while (fscanf(inFile, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Read character by character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) and use [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) to stop reading or filter out specific sets of characters?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want in case of e.g. a with a comma. Do you want to skip printing the word or do you want to print he word without the comma?

Comment: And what about numbers? E.g. how to handle "abc123def" ? Print nothing or print "abcdef" or print as two words like "abc" and "def"

Comment: An answer depends on some "specifications" you left out: What characters exactly do you want to include in words? For example, would [`isalnum()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum) fit? Do you allow underscores (i.e., allow an identifier syntax)? What about hyphens? Then: Do you want to stop reading for good when you hit characters that don't fit, do you want to skip them and continue with the next "word", do you want to output them as a word  on their own?

Answer (score 1):

Your function will not compile at all as it is returning value and it is declared as `void`

Read char by char and print only what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool load(const char *file)
{
    FILE *inFile = fopen(file , "r");
    if (inFile == NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }

    char word;
    int retval;
    while ((retval = fscanf(inFile, "%c", &word)) != EOF && retval == 1)
    {
        if(isalnum((unsigned char)word) || isspace((unsigned char)word))
            printf("%c", word);
    }
    fclose(inFile);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's necessary to check for `&& retval == 1` ? Can `retval` have other values than EOF and 1 ?

Comment: @4386427 With `"%c"`, certainly only `EOF, 1` are possible results, yet this example code may simple use `(retval = fscanf(inFile, "%c", &word)) != EOF && retval == 1` instead of `fscanf(inFile, "%c", &word) == 1` to illustrate program flow.

Comment: @4386427 I did it intentionally to show that fscanf return value has to be checked for more than one value - obviously in a less trivial example than this one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use `fscanf` to read words without symbols from a text file

Well, yes...

You can use a scanset to tell which characters to match. Like:

```
 %[a-zA-Z]
```

This will match/accept all upper and lower case letters and reject all other characters.

But... That will give you another problem. When the next character the the file doesn't match, the file pointer won't be advanced and you are kind of stuck. To handle that you need a way to skip non-matching characters, e.g. `fgetc` to read a single character.

Something like:

```
char word[32];
while (1)
{
  int res = fscanf(inFile, "%31[a-zA-Z]", word); // At most 31 characters and only letters
  if (res == EOF) break;
  if (res == 1)
  {
    printf("%s\n", word);
  }
  else
  {
    // Didn't match, skip a character
    if (fgetc(inFile) == EOF) break;
  }
}
```

With a file like:

```
Hallo World,    having()    fun  ....
Oh,yes...
```

the output is

```
Hallo
World
having
fun
Oh
yes
```

An alternative that only uses `fsanf` could be:

```
char word[32];
while (1)
{
  int res = fscanf(inFile, "%31[a-zA-Z]", word);  // Read letters
  if (res == EOF) break;
  if (res == 1)
  {
    printf("%s\n", word);
  }
  res = fscanf(inFile, "%31[^a-zA-Z]", word);  // Skip non-letters
  if (res == EOF) break;
}
```

Notice the `^` in the second scanset. It changes the meaning of the scanset to be "Don't match ...." So the code alternate between "Read a word consisting of letters" and "Skip everything not being letters" which is likely a better way of doing this than the `fgetc` method above.

That said, I normally prefer reading the file using `fgets` and then parse the buffer afterwards (e.g. using `sscanf`) but that's another story.